# Dead simple WCF - 405 Method not allowed

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

As far as I can tell **I have mimicked the *accepted* solutions of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228995/wcf-error-405-method-not-allowed) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944678/making-a-wcf-web-service-work-with-get-requests)**. Unless I'm blind (and I hope I am at this point), I have a spotless `app.config` for my very simple WCF service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RESTBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="Vert.Host.VertService.RSVPService">
    <endpoint
      address="/RSVP"
      binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="Vert.Host.VertService.IRSVP"
      behaviorConfiguration="RESTBehavior" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/Vert" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Here's the corresponding Service Contract and Implementation:

```
namespace Vert.Host.VertService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRSVP
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool Attending();

        [OperationContract]
        bool NotAttending();
    }

    public class RSVPService : IRSVP
    {
        public bool Attending()
            return true;

        public bool NotAttending()
            return true;
    }
}
```

I'm hosting everything via a console app:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create a ServiceHost
        using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RSVPService)))
        {
            serviceHost.Open();
            // The service can now be accessed.
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

All I want to do is stand this tiny service up, but I can't hit this endpoint with `http://localhost:8080/Vert/RSVP/Attending`. I still get `405 Method not allowed` as a response.I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015, IIS10, targeting .NET 4.6

Things I've tried from suggestions:

- I've given my service an explicitly-named behavior. No luck.

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to decorate the service methods with the `[WebGet]` attribute (reference `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll`)

I.e. changing the service from

```
public class RSVPService : IRSVP
{
    public bool Attending()
        return true;

    public bool NotAttending()
        return true;
}
```

to

```
public class RSVPService : IRSVP
{
    [WebGet]
    public bool Attending()
        return true;

    [WebGet]
    public bool NotAttending()
        return true;
}
```

Solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly not sure if this will make the difference, but mine has a link to service behaviour.  Give your service behaviour a name:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
```

Then link it to your service:

`<service name="Vert.Host.VertService.RSVPService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">`

Comment: First thing I tried post-posting this post. No luck :(

Comment: Don't know then.  I largely got mine working through blind luck.  I can only recommend turning on logging, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10905836).