# Error returning FileStream from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to set up a WCF service that will return an image, during testing this is what I was using, and it always worked.

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\pic.jpg");
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
return fs;
```

Now that last step is to return a generated image, just a simple box, nothing. Having tried many iterations with the same luck, ERR_CONNECTION_RESET errors always.

```
//trying to use this, but it causes in ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("image.jpg", FileMode.Create))
            {
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(300, 300);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

                g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 100, 100, 100, 100);

                g.Flush();
                bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                stream.Position = 0;
                return stream;
            }
```

When I compare the fs and stream, the only real difference I see if they have difference Handles 2560 vs 2564 respectively.

Here is the service contract

```
[ServiceContract]  
public interface IEmailService  
{  
    [OperationContract]  
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetImage/{token}/{guid}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]  
    Stream GetImage(string token, string guid);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try [enabling debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10905836).  Connection Reset errors (for me) were because of exceptions.

Comment: I don't think you'll want to use a `using` statement here - it disposes of the stream that you are trying to send.

Comment: @Internal Server Error
that was the issue, please post as answer and I will accept.